# iphone sdk how to parse a https url?

Tags: iphone, url, https, nsxmlparser

I am using an url in HTTPS mode. Now I need to parse this url link using NSXMLParser. I tried to parse it but am getting this error "Unable to download story feed from web site(Error code 5)". Is it possible to parse a https url? Why am getting this error? Is there any sample code or links? Kindly help me to get out of this. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure to understand, but if you've got an URL as a string, you can create a [`NSURL`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSURL_Class/Reference/Reference.html) object with the `urlWithString:` method.

```
NSURL * url = [ NSURL urlWithString: @"https://www.example.org/foo/bar.html" ];
```

Then, you'll have access to all URL parts, using the `NSURL` methods, like `host`, `path`, `scheme`, `port`, and so on...